# Rotating an object around X and Y axis issue in Unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, rotation, touch

I'm trying to rotate my camera on an android device by dragging the screen.
Dragging *horizontally* should move the camera to **left** or **right** and *vertically* **up** or **down**. The **Z axis** should be ignored, but if I make a diagonal drag on the screen it rotates the camera around the **Z axis**, so sometimes my camera gets an upside-down position.

Here is my code from the **Update()** method:

```
if (touch.phase  == TouchPhase.Moved)
{
    float x = touch.deltaPosition.x * rotationSensitivity * Time.deltaTime;
    float y = touch.deltaPosition.y * rotationSensitivity * Time.deltaTime;

    _camera.transform.Rotate(new Vector3(1, 0, 0), y, Space.Self);
    _camera.transform.Rotate(new Vector3(0, -1, 0), x, Space.Self); 

}
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to be rotating in local space with `Space.Self`? If you rotate forward around local `x`, that will change your next rotation around local `y` instead of rotating around the world's `y`.

Comment: Anyway I'm not changing the `z` on purpose, but in my game somehow, when the `x` and `y` are being changed, it will change instead the `z`.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong `transform.Rotate` overload

The first `Vector3` argument of the overload you are using is for the `axis` to rotate on.

I believe what you meant is to provide the direction, not axis, as such:

```
if (touch.phase  == TouchPhase.Moved)
{
    Vector2 rotation = (Vector2)touch.deltaPosition * rotationSensitivity * Time.deltaTime;

    _camera.transform.Rotate(Vector3.right * rotation.x, Space.Self);
    _camera.transform.Rotate(-Vector3.up * rotation.y, Space.Self); 
}
```

since this code is untested by me, i would also suggest to try this:

```
if (touch.phase  == TouchPhase.Moved)
{
    Vector2 rotation = (Vector2)touch.deltaPosition * rotationSensitivity * Time.deltaTime;

    _camera.transform.Rotate(transform.right * rotation.x, Space.World);
    _camera.transform.Rotate(-transform.up * rotation.y, Space.World); 
}
```

Edit: i had the `x` and `y` mixed up, fixed.

Comment: I've tried it, but my camera is still turning upside-down after diagonal drag.

Comment: Other than replacing values such as `new Vector3(1, 0, 0)` with the equivalent shorthand `Vector3.right`, how is this different from the code that OP posted?

Comment: Exactly how i explained it. He is using the wrong `transform.Rotate` overload. In the overload he is using, it is taking his `Vector3` as an *axis* which i am under the assumption he wanted it to be a rotational *direction*

Comment: @Andrew Ah, I missed the extra param. My bad.

Comment: I have tried it but still nothing, I also added a `rigidbody component` to my camera and froze the rotation around the `z`, but that still didn't resolved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to a similar problem [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/136174/im-rotating-an-object-on-two-axes-so-why-does-it-keep-twisting-around-the-thir)

```
void Update() {
float speed = lookSpeed * Time.deltaTime;

transform.Rotate(0f, Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * speed, 0f, Space.World);
transform.Rotate(-Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * speed,  0f, 0f, Space.Self);}
```